# How To modify quantmod package with GIT

Tags: r, git

I currently have quantmod installed. I would like to modify the source code.

Do I need to uninstall the current version?

I currently was trying

(1) Installed GIT

(2) then I went to **New Project>> Version Control >>create a new project form version control GIT** and when I click that I get this error

```
"Git was not detected in the system path. to create projects from GIT repositories you should install GIT and then restart Rstudio.  Not tha tif GIT is installed an not on the path then you can specify its location using the options dialog."
```

(3) So I went to the **global options>>GIT/SVN>>Git executable** and put this path

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe
```

(4) then I restarted RSTUDIO and now I get further so when I go to

**New Project>> Version Control >>create a new project form version control GIT>>CLONE GIT  REPISITORY**

Here it asks for a Repository URL, Project Directory name, and Create project as subdirectory of. Here is where I am unsure where I need to put this project so that the modification I make to the quantmod package will be picked up by my version of R

- For Repository URL I was going ot put: 
  https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod
- For Project Directory I am unsure: can you advise??
- For Create project as sub directory I am unsure: can you advise??

My R libraries are here:  C:\Users\me\Documents\R-3.1.2\library

Also currently I have quantmod installed here:
C:\Users\me\Documents\R-3.1.2\library\quantmod

Do I need to uninstall that current version?

Appendix:
On My computer GIT is here:  C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Git
On My computer R is here:    C:\Users\Me\Documents\R-3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

The project directory is just the name of the folder you will be putting the repo inside.  Generally it is the name of package to make things clear.  In your case `quantmod`.

The sub directory you can ignore unless you want to choose some other location (besides the current directory) for you code.

You don't need to uninstall the current version.  My usual recommendation is to just increment the subversion of the package in the DESCRIPTION file.  For example, increment:

```
Version: 1.0.1
```

to

```
Version: 1.0.2
```

Now when you rebuild and install you will have the new version.  If you need the original again, you can just reinstall the old one (i.e. `install.packages`).  Having both installed at the same time would likely result in conflicts between the packages and just causing a headache.

Comment: To be clear "Project Directory Name" = quantmod  and "Create project as a subdirectory of" is "C:\Users\me\Documents\R-3.1.2\library"? I am confused wont that overwrite the current verison?  The current quantmod package is there: C:\Users\me\Documents\R-3.1.2\library\quantmod.  When you say change the DESCRIPTION file where can I do that at? I guess I am confused about where this project needs to be located and how I install it so that R picks it up? It will have to be installed here: "C:\Users\me\Documents\R-3.1.2\library" correct? can you advise on those details? Thank you.

Comment: Don't create a subdirectory in your R library (leave this directory alone).  Just create it in some other folder where you want to keep you work.  The folder can theoretically be anywhere.  When you `build & install` with RStudio it will install in the correct location.  The DESCRIPTION file will be in the top directory of the package (once it is cloned).  You can see the file on the github repo page you link above.

Comment: Ok I think I am getting closer. I created a new project here C:\Users\me\Test\quantmod and in that quantmod folder there is an R folder with all the quantmod functions so I can see the source code. I need to modify the barChart().  My question is after I modify it how will my R application pickup the new version? In  R right now I can call the barChart() fucntion and how does it know to use the modified verison of barChart() and not the current verision that is here C:\Users\me\Documents\R-3.1.2\library\quantmod

Comment: @user3022875, if you click the `build & reload` button in RStudio, the new version of the package (your version) will be installed and use the `barChart` function you modified.